# pyspark - What is the difference between these two full outer joins?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, join, pyspark

Full Example [here](https://pastebin.com/b79s6gDG).

I am seeing two different outputs with these two ways of doing a full outer join on two dataframes in pyspark:

```
users1_df. \
    join(users2_df, users1_df.email == users2_df.email, 'full_outer'). \
    show()
```

This gives:

```
+--------------------+----------+---------+------+-------------+--------------------+----------+----------+------+---------------+
|               email|first_name|last_name|gender|   ip_address|               email|first_name| last_name|gender|     ip_address|
+--------------------+----------+---------+------+-------------+--------------------+----------+----------+------+---------------+
| alovett0@nsw.gov.au|   Aundrea|   Lovett|  Male|  62.72.1.143|                null|      null|      null|  null|           null|
|bjowling1@spiegel.de|   Bettine|  Jowling|Female|26.250.197.47|bjowling1@spiegel.de|    Putnam|Alfonsetti|Female|  167.97.48.246|
|                null|      null|     null|  null|         null|  lbutland7@time.com|     Lilas|   Butland|Female|109.110.131.151|
+--------------------+----------+---------+------+-------------+--------------------+----------+----------+------+---------------+
```

Notice that the `email` column is repeated and there are nulls for the email that is not present in both dataframes.

Now for this following code:

```
users1_df. \
    join(users2_df, 'email', 'full_outer'). \
    show()
```

I get the following:

```
+--------------------+----------+---------+------+-------------+----------+----------+------+---------------+
|               email|first_name|last_name|gender|   ip_address|first_name| last_name|gender|     ip_address|
+--------------------+----------+---------+------+-------------+----------+----------+------+---------------+
| alovett0@nsw.gov.au|   Aundrea|   Lovett|  Male|  62.72.1.143|      null|      null|  null|           null|
|bjowling1@spiegel.de|   Bettine|  Jowling|Female|26.250.197.47|    Putnam|Alfonsetti|Female|  167.97.48.246|
|  lbutland7@time.com|      null|     null|  null|         null|     Lilas|   Butland|Female|109.110.131.151|
+--------------------+----------+---------+------+-------------+----------+----------+------+---------------+
```

Notice that the `email` column is not repeated and there are also no nulls.

Am I missing something? Where is this behavior mentioned in the docs of [pyspark.join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

I had to do a little digging to understand the gap in the official documentation and the code. Here are my findings:

You have mentioned the `join` method call with two different approaches:

## 1. EXPLICIT JOIN CONDITION

```py
users1_df. \
    join(users2_df, users1_df.email == users2_df.email, 'full_outer'). \
    show()
```

Here the backend code has the following info as a function [doc](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py#L2790):

> When the join condition is explicited stated: `df.name == df2.name`, this will produce all records where the names match, as well as those that don't (since it's an outer join). If there are names in `df2` that are not present in `df` they will appear with `NULL` in the `name` column of `df`, and vice versa for `df2`.

This means when you perform the action `show` we are expected to see all the columns including the duplicate join column `email` resulting in the below output:

```
+--------------------+----------+---------+------+-------------+--------------------+----------+----------+------+---------------+
|email               |first_name|last_name|gender|ip_address   |email               |first_name|last_name |gender|ip_address     |
+--------------------+----------+---------+------+-------------+--------------------+----------+----------+------+---------------+
|alovett0@nsw.gov.au |Aundrea   |Lovett   |Male  |62.72.1.143  |null                |null      |null      |null  |null           |
|bjowling1@spiegel.de|Bettine   |Jowling  |Female|26.250.197.47|bjowling1@spiegel.de|Putnam    |Alfonsetti|Female|167.97.48.246  |
|null                |null      |null     |null  |null         |lbutland7@time.com  |Lilas     |Butland   |Female|109.110.131.151|
+--------------------+----------+---------+------+-------------+--------------------+----------+----------+------+---------------+
```

## 2. IMPLICIT JOIN CONDITION

Another flavor is using the implicit syntax of the `join` method:

```py
users1_df. \
    join(users2_df, 'email', 'full_outer'). \
    show()
```

Similarly the GitHub function [doc](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py#L2838) states:

> When you provide the column name directly as the join condition, Spark will treat both name columns as one, and will not produce separate columns for `df.name` and `df2.name`. This avoids having duplicate columns in the output.

This means the result of the explicit join condition is equal to the below implicit call:

```py
(users1_df.alias("u1")
 .join(users2_df.alias("u2"), 'email', 'full_outer')
 .selectExpr("u1.email", "u1.first_name", "u1.last_name", "u1.gender", "u1.ip_address",
             "u2.email", "u2.first_name", "u2.last_name", "u2.gender", "u2.ip_address")
 .show(1000, False))
```

Here, I have called the implicit syntax but used aliases (`u1` and `u2`) on the two dataframes `users1_df` and `users2_df` respectively, then eventually explicitly called out all the columns and the output is similar to the one produced by the explicit join condition:

```
+--------------------+----------+---------+------+-------------+--------------------+----------+----------+------+---------------+
|email               |first_name|last_name|gender|ip_address   |email               |first_name|last_name |gender|ip_address     |
+--------------------+----------+---------+------+-------------+--------------------+----------+----------+------+---------------+
|alovett0@nsw.gov.au |Aundrea   |Lovett   |Male  |62.72.1.143  |null                |null      |null      |null  |null           |
|bjowling1@spiegel.de|Bettine   |Jowling  |Female|26.250.197.47|bjowling1@spiegel.de|Putnam    |Alfonsetti|Female|167.97.48.246  |
|null                |null      |null     |null  |null         |lbutland7@time.com  |Lilas     |Butland   |Female|109.110.131.151|
+--------------------+----------+---------+------+-------------+--------------------+----------+----------+------+---------------+
```

Interestingly, if we apply the `coalesce` method on the join column `email` we get the output where there is only one `email` column:

```py
(users1_df.alias("u1")
 .join(users2_df.alias("u2"), 'email', 'full_outer')
 .selectExpr("coalesce(u1.email, u2.email) as email", "u1.first_name", "u1.last_name", "u1.gender",
             "u1.ip_address", "u2.first_name", "u2.last_name", "u2.gender", "u2.ip_address")
 .show(1000, False))
```

resulting in this output:

```
+--------------------+----------+---------+------+-------------+----------+----------+------+---------------+
|email               |first_name|last_name|gender|ip_address   |first_name|last_name |gender|ip_address     |
+--------------------+----------+---------+------+-------------+----------+----------+------+---------------+
|alovett0@nsw.gov.au |Aundrea   |Lovett   |Male  |62.72.1.143  |null      |null      |null  |null           |
|bjowling1@spiegel.de|Bettine   |Jowling  |Female|26.250.197.47|Putnam    |Alfonsetti|Female|167.97.48.246  |
|lbutland7@time.com  |null      |null     |null  |null         |Lilas     |Butland   |Female|109.110.131.151|
+--------------------+----------+---------+------+-------------+----------+----------+------+---------------+
```

This `coalesce` method generates the unique `email` column as per the documentation in GitHub and it just *avoids having duplicate columns in the output*. This is an experiment from my side to explain how the internals of pyspark decides how to generate the output during implicit joins, if I get hold of the method that does this, I will update this answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

When you give condition as a single column its always an equijoin on that column, spark merges the columns from both  dataframes, essentially you can think of this as coalesce(df1.email, df2.email) as pointed by @Lingesh (coalesce gives you first not-null value from columns provided)

however, when you give the condition explicitly, spark gives you all the columns and you'll have to handle them yourself.